# Aggregation to MSCI world return from subindicies

Tags: returns, log-returns

I have Bloomberg Data `PX_LAST` for the MSCI world (MXWO Index). I also have Bloomberg Data `PX_LAST` for all subindices for the MSCI world. My goal is to compute from the subindices the return of the index. I tried log and percentage returns and aggregating based on these formulas. I weighted them like that,
$$\textrm{weight Subindex}_i=\frac{\textrm{PX_LAST}_i}{\sum\textrm{PX_LAST}_j}
$$
[image]

Unfortunately, the results do not match the returns of the index itself.

**Where can I find information on how the MSCI world index is aggregated from its subindices?**

**Does anybody know how they are aggregated?**

I found this link https://www.msci.com/index-methodology but wasn't lucky finding any info there either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document you're looking for is [MSCI Index Calculation Methodology](https://www.msci.com/eqb/methodology/meth_docs/MSCI_June2017_IndexCalcMethodology.pdf). At a very high level, MSCI indices are market-cap weighted. A crude aggregation would require that you weight the component returns by their market cap as a percentage of total market cap. For example, US currently has a 59% weighting in the index (where 59% = US market cap / world market cap). Doing this should get you close, but if you need exact values, you need to follow the formulas in the document precisely.

Comment: where can i get the market cap data? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It's not free. You can potentially use data from https://www.world-exchanges.org/home/ as a proxy. On the other hand, may I ask why you want to do this, given aggregate indices are readily available?

Comment: I would like to use it to benchmark different VaR models for the MSCI world. I would like to also add multivariate models as well as univariate ones. For the multivariates I need to know how the returns are aggregated.